# Is it possible to edit Schematic created using CircuitLab?

Tags: support

Is it possible to edit Schematic created using CircuitLab?

When attempting to edit an [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105246/8697) the source shows "please don't edit this section directly.
 Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead." but there is NO "edit" link that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the schematic there should be this:

[image]

If you click edit for the main question, in the markdown view above the schematic is:

```
<!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->
```

Without leaving the edit interface, if you scroll down to look at the marked up preview, the line below the schematic now reads:

[image]

Sneaky.

Comment: Thanks. I have never seen the preview, but discovered a "show preview" link.